# Cordova Windows App not building appx with dependencies folder

Tags: cordova, uwp, visual-studio-cordova, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to build appx installer file for an application we built using Visual Studio and Apache Cordova Tools. The build is successful and I get the appx file alongside the certificate and other powershell scripts. But when I install the appx on a mobile device the app does not even launch. Upin inspection I noticed that there is no longer a dependencies folder.

I have older installer files generated on another build machine. These installer files include a folder called "Dependencies" as well as other files. the dependencies folder has arch folders with three .NET dependecies as .appx files.

I tried to include the package dependencies as below in the appxmanifest file within `package.appxmanifest` file, but the dependencies are still not getting picked up. When VS 2017 generates the `windows10.appxmanifest` file it shows my changes for `Identity`, but not for `dependencies`. Not sure what I am missing.

I am using the following software.

VS2017 15.6.7
Cordova: 6.3.1
node.js: 4.4.3
npm: 2.15

cordova-windows-platform: 4.4.2

My Package.appxmanifest file dependencies xml block

```
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily MaxVersionTested="10.0.17134.0" MinVersion="10.0.10240.0" Name="Windows.Universal" />
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00" MinVersion="14.0.25426.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.3" MinVersion="1.3.24201.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.4" MinVersion="1.4.24201.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
  </Dependencies>
```

How can I get the dependencies folder created for this application during the appx generation using the "Create App Packages" menu on VS 2017

I have removed and re-added the platform with no luck...

Right clicking on Dependencies gives below options.

[image: dependencies]

Comment: What's wrong with the Build > Build Solution menu option? Can you deploy that appx or emulate it correctly?

Comment: Hi. The build is successful and I get appx generated. But, after installing the app it does not launch. Just flashes the launch screen and dies.

Comment: My question is how can I get the dependencies flowing through to build. I crated different appxmanifest files in res/native/windows to get them to appxmanifest file that is generated. But no luck. I don't know if I need to get dependencies as bower or neget packages. Any assistance will be much appreciated

Comment: @andreszs: Any ideas please...

Answer (score 0):

In the **Solution Explorer** pane, do you see the *Dependencies* (or *References*) item with an exclamation sign? In this case, right click on it and select *Restore Packages* to have them installed...

[image: Visual Studio Solution Explorer]

Also, what **Gradle** version do you have? I recommend using 4.x at most with Visual Studio, check out this [guide to change gradle version in Windows](https://www.andreszsogon.com/upgrading-gradle-version-for-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/).

Comment: :: Thanks for your response. 

I am using gradle wrapper - v 2.13.

My project has a dependencies folder, but when I right-click on each subfolder, I get no option to install dependencies. The image is at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Well try switching to gradle 4.1 using the guide I provided, then rebuild the app (from scratch). Also you should upgrade to Cordova 7.1.0, the last version that actually works fine with Visual Studio.